# Check PHP Module Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Hello guys I am trying to use the Laravel Stats Tracker by Antonio Ribeiro and I want to install the GeoIP package but it requires me not to have the PHP Module installed. How can I check or find if the PHP Module is installed in Laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to do it programmatically, use the [`extension_loaded`](http://php.net/extension_loaded) function.

```
if(extension_loaded('geoip')) {
    // GeoIP extension is loaded
}
```

Another option would be using [`function_exists`](http://php.net/function_exists) on one of the module's functions.

```
if(function_exists('geoip_db_avail')) {
    // GeoIP extension is loaded
}
```

If you're just wondering if **you've** got it loaded in PHP, you can take a look at the output of `phpinfo()` (in a browser) or `php -i` in the command line.

Comment: I can see the module now. Thank you ceejayoz!